# Why does .Pfx exist in my Certificates Collection but not my .Cer?

Tags: c#, azure, ssl, x509certificate, x509certificate2

I have uploaded a couple of SSL cerificates to Azure.  One is a.cer and one is a .pfx.  I followed the advice in this [Azure Blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/27/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/).  I uploaded using the management portal.

I have the 'WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATE' in my App Setting section and have the two correct thumbprints comma separated.

When I remotely debug my Azure Web Job, I can see that only the .pfx is in the certStore.Certificates collection.

Can I access my .cer in this way?

Answer (score 1):

pfx is a secure container which has both your Private and Public keys, while .cer is just the public Key. 
The public is needed only by the clients to verify integrity of the signature / decrypt content. While your job will need the private key to sign/encrypt the data.

Both public and private keys can be extracted from the PFX using X509Certificate2 class from .NET. It has a property [PublicKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.publickey(v=vs.110).aspx).

Why you uploaded .cer at first place ? You do not need it for SSL with Web Apps.

P.S. [Azure Key Vault](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/key-vault/) may the solution you are looking for.

Comment: thanks.  The .cer contains only the public key of a third party partner's web service.  I need to use it to create an X509SecurityToken that is passed to a WebServicesClientProtocol.SetServiceCredentials method when establishing communication with them.

Comment: I don't think I can create a .pfx without the private key of that .cer.

Comment: no you can't create PFX without the private key ... hm, in Web Roles you could add both types of certificates ... From what I see only SSL certs are supported in Web Apps (but I may be wrong). Since .CER is just a public Key, you can put it in your App_Data folder. Yes, not best practice, and this "public" key may be assigned only for your service plan at the 3rd party, but right now I don't have a solution for managing your public certs in Azure Web Apps directly.

Comment: It is an Azure website.  Is that possible?  It is a new job I have started and I  I don't think they have web roles.  Also, I'm pretty new to Azure. so I might be talking rubbish...

Comment: Yeah, at first I had embedded it in a resource file and accessed it but we will have multiple environments and I wanted to control everything via app settings on the portal.  I suppose as its only their public key it is not the end of the world - I can put them in app_data or embed them and access the correct one via a string in app settings.  Our own pfx will still be held on Azure.  Thanks for your help.